# Can a sudo user read the command file for which sudo access is enabled?

Tags: linux, sudo, elevated-privileges

I have a normal Linux user say user1 , and it has sudo access to a command /usr/local/bin/command.sh .

/usr/local/bin/command.sh has 700 permission. So therefore the user1 is successfully able to run

`sudo /usr/local/bin/command.sh`

Now I was wondering that with sudo command the privilege escalation is happening. is there any possibility or even a remote possibility that he can read the contents of /usr/local/bin/command.sh ? Is sudo by design a very strict command based implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one word answer is: No.

> (…) So therefore the user1 is successfully able to run (…)

Strictly speaking it is not `user1` who is running that executable, but the user switched to using sudo (in your case root), who of course can also read that file. Now if there's a vulnerability in the executable executable run via sudo, you could piggyback on that to read an arbitrary. file, but that would be *bad*.

Comment: So by design sudo only executes the command on an as is basis. Nothing more nothing less. And ofcourse as a root user in my case. So unless sudo itself has some vulnerability or the executed command is exploitable, the command file being executed is unreadable. I want to make some script and give access to a regular user without revealing its nuts and bolts. Thanks.

Comment: @KirtiSingh: Well, consider that your user might be able to boot the machine using a USB thumb drive, or a LiveCD. Then your script will no longer be "unreadable" – unless you put it into an encrypted partition, which is encrypted using some form of measured boot protected key in a TPM or similar. In general it's a foold errand to attempt to keep secret the contents of anything that's running on a computer.